# React native onPress with TouchableOpacity combined with elevation show ugly shadow

Tags: reactjs, react-native, styled-components

Using `RN 0.63.4` and trying to implement a touchable card in `Android` environment.

The code is pretty simple:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handlePress()}>
    <ArticleContainer>
        ....
    </ArticleContainer>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

This is the CSS for the `ArticleContainer`

```
const ArticleContainer = styled.View`
    height: 170px;
    width: 320px;
    border-radius: 11px;
    padding: 13px;
    margin: 20px 15px 10px 20px;
    elevation: 5;
    background-color: white;
`;
```

The UI looks fine when not touched, even the elevation looks pretty good:

[image]

But when trying to touch it, it becomes so ugly, look at the weird shadows and border:

[image]

Found only a few answers in StackOverflow and one in the official GitHub which both didn't work for me.

Is there is a way to solve that?

Answer (score 11):

#### Solution:

I recently faced similar issue. What worked for me was to apply shadows on `TouchableOpacity` instead of the `View` inside it.

##### What was causing the issue?

Not sure about it, but I think that when the shadows were applied on `View`, the `TouchableOpacity` will drop the opacity of its child i.e `View` on being pressed, which somehow did not effect its shadows, leaving them exposed.

That being said I am really not sure about why applying shadows to `TouchableOpacity` worked.

##### Other possible cause/solution

- `backgroundColor` - In many cases not setting a background color on the component with shadows, causes shadows to not behave properly. Just set it to transparent if you don't want any background color.

##### Note:

The solution worked for me but I am not sure if it is the best solution or even if it will work for you as the behavior might be different depending on the platform and also if you are using **expo**.

- I personally was **NOT** using **expo** and was testing my application on **Android**

#### Edit:

I tried to reproduce the issue and apply the solution on **expo**. Below images shows `TouchableOpacity` in a pressed state.

[image: Shadow on child View] [image: Shadow on TouchableOpacity]

Comment: I managed to solve this issue on android by putting a property on my view called, renderToHardwareTextureAndroid,


something like this


<TouchableOpacity>
   <View renderToHardwareTextureAndroid>
{.....other content.....}
   </View>
</TouchableOpacity>

Answer (score 3):

I've faced the exact same problem. Just found that it was caused by the `elevation` in the style. Removed it and solved.

## Edit

`elevation` + `TouchableOpacity` = ugly.

Found a better solution. I use `TouchableNativeFeedback` for Android, and `TouchableOpacity` for iOS.

With `TouchableNativeFeedback`, you need to set `background` and `useForeground` props. Note that you also need to set `overflow: hidden` to the inner view. More details [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6480).

Here's my card view:

```js
interface Props extends TouchableWithoutFeedbackProps {
  style?: ViewStyle;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}

export default function CardView({style, children, onPress}: Props) {
  const card = (
    <View
      style={{
        shadowColor: 'gery',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        padding: 18,
        overflow: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'hidden' : 'visible',

        // iOS
        shadowOffset: {width: 0, height: 2},
        shadowRadius: 18,
        shadowOpacity: 0.2,
        borderRadius: 12,

        // Android
        elevation: 8,

        ...style,
      }}>
      {children}
    </View>
  );

  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    return (
      <TouchableNativeFeedback
        onPress={e => onPress?.call(undefined, e)}
        background={TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple('#00000040', false)}
        useForeground={true}>
        {card}
      </TouchableNativeFeedback>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={e => onPress?.call(undefined, e)}
        activeOpacity={0.5}>
        {card}
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the styles directly to TouchableOpacity

**Instead of this**

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handlePress()}>
    <View style={your_styles}>
       ....
    </View >
</TouchableOpacity>
```

**Add Styles directly to TouchableOpacity**

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handlePress()} style={your_styles}>
    
       ....
   
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the activeOpacity prop of TouchableOpacity (the default is 0.2) and Add backfaceVisibility: 'hidden' to your ArticleContainer style.
Or you can use touchablewithoutfeedback, that should do the trick.

Comment: activeOpacity with backfaceVisibility: 'hidden' still looks ugly. and touchablewithoutfeedback doesn't help me, because now I don't have the indication of pressing.

Comment: Then I'll try to use TouchableHighlight, that might look better than using TouchableOpacity.

what's the difference between them:
TouchableHighlight: it Darkens or lightens the background of the element on press- depends on the defined activeOpacity.
TouchableOpacity: Lightens the opacity of the entire element when pressed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer} >

         <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Text</Text>

</TouchableOpacity>
```

style:

```
buttonContainer: {
        elevation: 10,
        width: '100%',
        borderRadius: 12,
        elevation: 10,
        marginVertical: 10,
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        alignItems: 'center',
    }, 
    buttonText: {
        lineHeight: 50,
        color: "#000000",
    },
```

[image]

[image]

Thank You.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Thanks for your contribution. Please note that while "code only" Answers are accepted, they are generally discouraged. Consider [editing your post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71718267/5411817) to add an explanation as to how/why your code solves the OP's issue. Sometimes a link to documentation can also help. Quality answers help visitors learn something they can use to apply to their own coding issues, thus they tend to receive more upvotes over time. Explanations help more people overall, & tend to be the most appreciated. Looking forward to more contributions. Happy coding.